# Сохранение и загрузка в двусвязном списке

Tags: c, двусвязный-список

Пытаюсь сделать сохранение в файл и выгрузку из файла двусвязного списка. Оно сохраняет данные, но если открыть файл, то там только китайские иероглифы, а если выгрузить в ОП, а потом попробовать напечатать данные из ОП, то программы падает. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <locale.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <malloc.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #define MAX 20

    FILE *baza;

    typedef struct inform
    {
            char *name;
            char *group;
            char *form;
            char *doza;
            char *day1;
            char *month1;
            char *year1;
            char *day2;
            char *month2;
            char *year2;
            char *price;

    } INF;


    typedef struct list_elem
    {
            INF inf;
            struct list_elem *next, *prev;
    } APTEKA;

    APTEKA *head, *tail;

    void InputData(INF* pinf);
    void InsertEl(INF data);
    void AddEl(APTEKA* pnew, APTEKA* pold);
    void PrintList(void);
    void Save(void);
    void Load(INF* pinf);


    int main()
    {
        SetConsoleCP (1251);
        SetConsoleOutputCP (1251);
        setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");


        INF input;
        char n[MAX];



        while(1)
        {
            printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
            puts("\nСписок доступных команд"
            "\n 0  || Выход из программы"
            "\n 1  || Добавить элемент;"
            "\n 10 || Сохранить данные;"
            "\n 11 || Загрузить данные;");
            printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");

            printf("Введите номер команды: ");
            scanf("%s",n);




            switch(atoi(n))
            {
                //Добавление
                case 1:

                    InputData(&input);
                    InsertEl(input);
                    break;

                //Вывод всех данных
                case 4:
                    PrintList();
                    break;

                case 10:
                    Save();
                    break;
                case 11:
                    Load(&input);
                    break;
                //Выход из программы
                case 0:
                    exit(1);
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }



     return 0;
    }


    void InputData(INF* pinf)
    {




        char buf[MAX];
        float buf1;

        printf("Введите название:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->name=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->name, buf);

        printf("Введите группу:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->group=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->group, buf);


        printf("Введите форму:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->form=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->form, buf);


        printf("Введите дозу:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->doza=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->doza, buf);

        buf1=atoi(pinf->doza);

               printf("Введите день выпуска:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->day1=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->day1, buf);


        printf("Введите месяц выпуска:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->month1=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->month1, buf);


        printf("Введите год выпуска:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->year1=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->year1, buf);


        printf("Введите день конца срока годности:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->day2=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->day2, buf);


        printf("Введите месяц срока годности:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->month2=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->month2, buf);



        printf("Введите год срока годности:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->year2=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->year2, buf);


        printf("Введите цену:");
        fflush(stdin); gets(buf);
        pinf->price=(char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        strcpy(pinf->price, buf);


        system("cls");
        puts("\nПрепарат успешно добавлен.");


    }
    void InsertEl(INF data)
    {
        APTEKA *pel, *pins;

        pel = (APTEKA*)malloc(sizeof(APTEKA));
        pel->inf=data;

        if(head == NULL)
        {
            pel->next = pel->prev=NULL;
            head = tail = pel;
            return;
        }
        pins = head;

        while(pins!=NULL)
            pins=pins->next;
        AddEl(pel, pins);
    }
    void AddEl(APTEKA* pnew, APTEKA* pold)
    {
          if(pold == head)
        {
            head->prev=pnew;
            pnew->next=head;
            pnew->prev=NULL;
            head=pnew;
            return;
        }

        if(pold!=NULL)
        {
            pnew->next=pold;
            pnew->prev=pold->prev;
            pold->prev->next=pnew;
            pold->prev=pnew;
        }else{
            tail->next=pnew;
            pnew->prev=tail;
            pnew->next=NULL;
            tail=pnew;
        }

    }
    void PrintList(void)
    {


       APTEKA* pel = head;

       /* Вывод таблицы */
        /* вывод заголовков */
        printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
        printf("|Препараты Аптеки                                                                             |\n");
        printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
        printf("| Название    |     Группа    |   Форма   |  Доза  |  Дата выпуска  |  Срок годности |  Цена  |\n");
        printf("|-------------|---------------|-----------|--------|----------------|----------------|--------|\n");
        while (pel!=NULL)
       {

        /* вывод строк фактических данных */
        printf("|%13s|%15s|%11s|%8s|    %2s.%2s.%4s  |   %2s.%2s.%4s   |%8s|\n", pel->inf.name, pel->inf.group, pel->inf.form, pel->inf.doza, pel->inf.day1, pel->inf.month1, pel->inf.year1,pel->inf.day2, pel->inf.month2, pel->inf.year2, pel->inf.price);
        printf("|-------------|---------------|-----------|--------|----------------|----------------|--------|\n");

           pel=pel->next;
       }
       printf("|                                                                                             |\n");
       printf("|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|\n");
    }
void Save()
{
    APTEKA* pel=head;

    if( (baza = fopen("D:\\baza.txt", "a")) == NULL)
    {
        puts("\nОшибка сохранения");
        exit(1);
    }

    while(pel!=NULL)
    {
        fwrite(&pel->inf, sizeof (pel->inf), 1, baza);
        pel=pel->next;
    }
    fclose(baza);

}

    void Load(INF* pinf)
    {

        INF input;

        if( (baza = fopen("D:\\baza.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        {
            puts("\nОшибка чтения");
            exit(1);
        }

        while(fread(&pinf, sizeof (pinf), 1, baza) == 1)
        {
            fread(&pinf, sizeof (pinf), 1, baza);
            InsertEl(input);
        }
        fclose(baza);
    }
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опять...

Вы записываете и читаете вот таким способом -

```
fread(&pinf, sizeof (pinf), 1, baza)
```

**адреса** в полях структуры `INF`, а не строки.

Примерно так - жена говорит собраться в отпуск и в машину в багажник сложить, ну, там, матрас надувной, палатку, мангал и шампуры - ну, в общем, барахло. Вы в багажник кладете бумажки с надписями "Матрас - на антресолях", "Палатка - на балконе" и т.д. Так вот сохраняете в файл...

По приезду на место читает - вынимаете из бумажника бумажки с надписями, где что лежит. Но хуже того, что шкаф теперь совсем другой, балкон тоже, так что втык от жены - это примерно и есть результат вот такого хранения и попытку раскрыть палатку, которой нет...

**Update**

Примерный набросок, как бы писал-читал я. Набросок - надо дописать проверки и т.п.

```
void writeStr(const char * s, FILE * f)
{
    int l = strlen(s);
    fwrite(&l,sizeof(int),1,f);
    fwrite(s,l,1,f);
}

char* readStr(FILE * f)
{
    int l;
    fread(&l,sizeof(int),1,f);
    char * s = malloc(l+1);
    fread(s,l,1,f);
    s[l] = 0;
    return s;
}
```

Потом запись в файл структуры выглядит как

```
void writeInf(INF*i,FILE*f)
{
    writeStr(i->name,f);
    writeStr(i->group,f);
    ...
}
```

Ну, и чтение:

```
INF* readInf(FILE*f)
{
    INF * i = malloc(sizeof(INF));
    i->name  = readStr(f);
    i->group = readStr(f);
    ...
    return i;
}
```

Примерно так...

Comment: Прошу прощения, еще учусь. Не могли бы подсказать, как исправить.

Comment: Писать каждую строку из структуры отдельно. Потом точно так же читать - с выделением памяти через `malloc` и настройкой указателей.

Comment: А отправлять в файл каждый элемент структуры через fwrite?

Comment: См. обновленный ответ.

Comment: Благодарю. Буду разбираться.